# c, segmentation fault

Tags: c, if-statement, segmentation-fault

Can anyone please tell me why I have segmentation fault here?

```
   void *dispatcher_threadloop(void * queue){

//thread loop of the dispatch thread- pass the tast to one of worker thread
dispatch_queue_t *dQueue;

printf("message-boss1");
dQueue = (dispatch_queue_t *)queue;
if (dQueue->HEAD!=NULL){
    for(;;){
        sem_wait(dQueue->queue_thread_semaphore);
        //TODO
    }
}

printf("message-boss2");

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`queue` is probably 0 or points to some invalid location in memory.

If you want more help, see http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't feel like checking `dQueue` against null, or if `dQueue` being null should never happen, try an assertion

```
dispatch_queue_t *dQueue = queue;

assert(dQueue!=NULL)
```

On the other hand, you should probably post the origin of the `queue` variable.

Comment: I'd definetly go with an assertion then.

Comment: What didn't work? The assertion? What were you expecting and what happened?